# Adding comments inside tensorflow object detection pipeline configuration file

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

How to add comments inside tensorflow object detection API's pipeline configuration file (typically named `pipeline.conf`)?

The [corresponding official documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) does not mention any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `# comment here` wherever you want.
Keep in mind that the pipeline.config is written into the model_dir. Therefore, if it is the same directory as your pipeline.config, it will be overridden, and the comments will be deleted. You can simply avoid this by naming the pipeline.config file you use differently.